# Android : How to execute code when bluetooth connection disconnected to particular device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wanna know how to execute a particular code when my fone's bluetooth device is connected to any device and also i want to execute another code when my fone disconnects from that bluetooth connection?
Please provide the code with proper comments.

Comment: Is there anything else you want?

Comment: Have you tried Tasker?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm

Comment: @ramaral if you can provide snippet for the purpose then i would be really glad.

Comment: @Taegost I have no idea what is tasker? Is it something like broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Taegost I dont want to buy any app dude. Im looking for android code for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#) to handle that:

In on manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<receiver android:name=".MyBluetoothReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />           
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Write class MyBluetoothReceiver derived from BroadcastReceiver. Override the onReceive method and for each action implement your code:

```
public class MyBluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(
          "android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED")){

           // code for Bluetooth connect
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals(
          "android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED")){

          //code for Bluetooth disconnect;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir i will check it and will reply back

Comment: I tried your code but doesn't worked for me, I simple added a toast for both connected and disconnected but it doesn't seems to be working. I tested on the real device.

Comment: I can also give my complete project, I did exactly as u said but toast is not showing

Comment: this code im using in onReceive()
     Toast.makeText(context, "RECEIVER CALLED!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(intent.getAction().equals(
          "android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED")){

           // code for Bluetooth connect
         
         Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTED!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals(
          "android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED")){

          //code for Bluetooth disconnect;
         Toast.makeText(context, "DISCONNECTED!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Comment: Toast of RECEIVER CALLED is working fine, even toast of disconnected also working but toast of connected is not working and yes i have given permissions.

Comment: That always works for me. Make sure you aren't connected when you test. What device type are you try connect with?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper answer I found :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String action = intent.getAction();

    // When discovery finds a device
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                      //you can get name by device.getName()

    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACL_DISCONNECTED
            .equals(action)) {

    }
}
};
```

Comment: where did you find this?